# Difficulty in particle animation

Tags: particles

I am currently making an animation of a hand picking a pile of sand(beach sand) and i cant find a way to make the hand pick up the sand or make it interact with each other...any suggestions?.

Comment: Is the hand animated?

Comment: you need to make a particle physics simulation https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?204008-Particle-system-simulating-sand

Comment: You also want to [enable collision](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/collision.html) for the hand.